# Reading Data from XML to HTML Table

Tags: php, html, xml

Hi I am trying to read the record from XML file to my HTML Table. The code i am trying to acheive this is not working and only showing blank page. Can you please help me where i am wrong?

Here is my XML File Data:

```
<staff><info><staffid>test</staffid><email>testtest@gtes.com</email><surname>test</surname><givename>test</givename><address>test</address></info></staff>
```

Here is my PHP/HTML code where i want to display my html Record.

```
<?php



                        $file="staff.xml";


                        $xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Error Loading Data");
                        foreach($xml->staff as $staff){

                        ?>
                        <tbody><tr>

                            <td><?php echo $staff->staffid; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $staff->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $staff->surname; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $staff->givename; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $staff->address; ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody>

                        <?php 
                            }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incoreact path when parsing that xml, Change your foreach loop

`foreach($xml->staff as $staff)`

with

`foreach ($xml->info as $stafs)`

My worked testing code

```
$url = 'test.xml';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$enc = json_encode($xml);
foreach ($xml->info as $staff) {
    echo $staff->staffid;
}
```

Hope it helps